# Change type to string error

Tags: java

I am trying to add an integer to my database but it wont let me.

```
    int count =0;
    public void editHighScores(){

    HashMap<String, String> queryValues = new HashMap<String, String>();
    queryValues.put("totalWins", count);

    myDatabase.insertHighScores(queryValues);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have define the Map to accept `String` keys and `String` values, so you can'y put an `int` as value.

If you are not sure the value type, then Keep it as `Object` like

```
HashMap<String, Object> queryValues = new HashMap<String, Object>();
```

Or, if you know values will be always int only, then define like

```
HashMap<String, Integer> queryValues = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, HashMap is expecting two strings. Try doing `HashMap<String, Integer> = new HashMap<String, Integer>();`

Comment: `int` as generic type? not possible

Comment: It would have to be `HashMap<String, Integer>`.